# Tikz draw at (baseline + south west) combined

Tags: tikz-pgf, baseline

If i run `\test{ap}` and `\test{ap}` i get

[image]

Here is the code

```
\newcommand{\test}[1]{
\tikz[baseline=(arced node.base)]{
            \node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (arced node) {#1};
            \draw [line width=2pt,transform canvas={yshift=-0.5mm},color=black] (arced node.south west) parabola [parabola height=-1.5mm] (arced node.south east);
        }
}
```

I want that both parabola are at the same height. Either starting at baseline or starting after depth. Do you guys have an idea how to manage that?

Comment: Please make your code snippet an MWE that people can just copy and compile in order to see the problem (cf. my answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `base west` anchor.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{
  \tikz [baseline=(arced node.base)] {
    \node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (arced node) {#1};
    \draw [line width=2pt,transform canvas={yshift=-0.5mm},color=black] (arced node.base west) parabola [parabola height=-1.5mm] (arced node.base east);
  }
}

\begin{document}

ab \test{ab} \test{ap} ap

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: perfect, thanks!

Comment: One question: How can I istead of base west, set to "midline west" and "capline west"?

Comment: @BilalYilmaz There is no predefined anchor for that. Ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Some other alternatives to adjust vertical alignment when some descendants (?) are missing. Include `\strut` or a `\vphantom` or just a `text depth` into node's definition.

Nodes are drawn to see the effect of every option to their size. Alignment is correct and `south` anchors are used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{
  \tikz [baseline=(arced node.base)] {
    \node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, draw] (arced node) {#1\strut};
    \draw [line width=2pt,transform canvas={yshift=-0.5mm},color=black] (arced node.south west) parabola [parabola height=-1.5mm] (arced node.south east);
  }
}

\newcommand{\testa}[1]{
  \tikz [baseline=(arced node.base)] {
    \node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, draw] (arced node) {#1\vphantom{p}};
    \draw [line width=2pt,transform canvas={yshift=-0.5mm},color=black] (arced node.south west) parabola [parabola height=-1.5mm] (arced node.south east);
  }
}

\newcommand{\testb}[1]{
  \tikz [baseline=(arced node.base)] {
    \node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, draw, text depth=.25ex] (arced node) {#1};
    \draw [line width=2pt,transform canvas={yshift=-0.5mm},color=black] (arced node.south west) parabola [parabola height=-1.5mm] (arced node.south east);
  }
}

\begin{document}

ab \test{ab} \test{ap} ap \testa{ab} \testa{ap} ap \testa{ab} \testa{ap}

\end{document}
```

[image]